# What are the contents of this set? Discrete mathematics, set theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm having a debate with other freshman computer science students about the contents of a set defined like this:
$$
M_n := \{A\,| \,\,\emptyset \subsetneq A \subsetneq \{1,...,n\}\}
$$

Whats would for e.g. a set $M_4$ contain?

Comment: Well, what do you think $M_4$ would contain?  And what controversy do you see associated with that?

Comment: Formatting note:  \emptyset looks better than \phi.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just {1,2,3,4} but I heard that I should treat this like a Power set definition

Comment: The part $\emptyset \subsetneq A$ means that $\emptyset$ is a *proper* subset of $A$, that means that $A$ cannot be empty.

Comment: The definition specifically rules out $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $A=\emptyset$ (assuming we have $n=4$ here).

Comment: You should absolutely be treating this "like a power set definition".  The elements of $M_4$ will be the non-empty proper subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\}$... that is to say $M_4 = \{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\dots,\{2,3,4\}\}$ and $M_4$ will have all the elements that the powerset of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ has except for $\emptyset$ and $\{1,2,3,4\}$ itself and so will have $2^4 - 2$ elements.

Comment: For $n=4$ the part $A \subsetneq \{1,...,4 \}$ means that $A$ is a *proper* subset of $\{ 1,2,3,4 \}$.

Comment: Perhaps call $M_n$ the set of non-trivial subsets of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$